# How to connect GCP VM instance using android Cloud Console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've just created a VM instance at GCP with os-login feature enabled. I can connect via ssh using web browser console, SDK, but, I can't connect using the android app called Cloud Console.

Is there any extra step while configuring os-login to use the offical google android app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe everything should work out of the box. There certainly isn't mention of any extra documentation on the [Cloud Console Mobile App](https://cloud.google.com/console-app/) landing page.

I spun up a new instance (`europe-west4-b`, `n1-standard-1`, `debian-9-stretch-v20190813`) and set the metadata to `enable-oslogin` = `TRUE` and I managed to connect right away, albeit from an iOS device.

I would suggest trying different networks (WiFi, 3G/4G), double check any suspicious firewall tags on the instance, maybe even try from a different device. If the connection attempt did reach the server, chances are there's at least one log entry mentioning it in `/var/log` (`/var/log/auth.log` in Debian is a good place to start).

Comment: Thanks mickey. I've checked /var/log/auth.log and this is what happens when I try to log in via ssh using the mobile app: Received disconnect from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 47873:11: Closed due to user request. [preauth]. Default ssh rules are enabled by default.

Comment: Well there is definitively an attempt to connect, meaning your server is reachable from your phone. This could be some kind of [timeout issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102502/meaning-of-connection-closed-by-xxx-preauth-in-sshd-logs), some kind of [key issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/847272/connection-closed-by-ip-preauth), or other stuff related to SSH. But this is most certainly not a problem with the Android App itself.